# The package's version is not displayed using pip freeze when using docker container

Tags: python, pip

I am using docker to build a base python container as dev env

I am using `continuumio/anaconda3:2023.09-0`

Everything runs well

However, when I run `pip freeze > requirement.txt` to store all package's version info.

most of the package is followed by `@ file:///...` rather than its version.

It seems due to some packages were installed locally. However, that is hard for me to manage the version and replicate the environment.

I hope I could get a requiremnent.txt which has all packages displaying clearly the version:

```
package_a == 1.1.1
package_b == 2.2.2
```

is that possible?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat I think so, thanks! I should close my question, then